# Limiting the max length of window using triggers

Tags: java, session, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to figure out how to limit the maximum length of a session. While doing triggering. My current trigger looks like this:

```
return AfterEach.inOrder(
                // speculatively trigger
                Repeatedly.forever(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(earlyFiringInterval).orFinally(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow())),
                // finally trigger for late
                Repeatedly.forever(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(lateFiringInterval)));
```

This works fine as it triggers every `earlyFiringInterval` time units, till watermark passes the end of the window and then it triggers every `lateFiringInterval` time units beyond that.

Unfortunately, there is a possibility that a session can go on for days, it would cause the window to remain open for a very long time and cause the watermark to be held behind. I am trying to build a trigger that can "cut" the window so that either:

- No session can be longer than some `maxSessionLength` time (in event time).
- Or, limiting the session to some `maxSessionLength` number of events in the pane. - this works out as it's in accumulating mode. (not ideal)

So, far I have:

```
return AfterEach.inOrder(
                Repeatedly
                        // speculatively trigger at every 'earlyFiringInterval'
                        .forever(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(earlyFiringInterval)
                        // terminate trigger when any of the following conditions are met:
                        //  * We have collected either 'maxEventCount' events in the pane
                        //  * Watermark has passed the window
                        .orFinally(AfterFirst.of(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(maxEventCount), AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()))),
                Repeatedly
                        // trigger for late data at every 'lateFiringInterval'
                        .forever(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(lateFiringInterval)))
                        .orFinally(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(maxEventCount));
```

I am wondering if this is the way to go or if there are better ways to do "limit the window size".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can allow the watermark to advance while maintaining full fidelity of your sessions by specifying an [`OutputTimeFn`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/windowing/OutputTimeFn) like so:

```java
Window.into(Sessions.withGapDuration(...))
      .withOutputTimeFn(OutputTimeFns.outputAtEndOfWindow())
```

Just like a `CombineFn` determines the *value* that is output from a grouping transform (we can think of `GroupByKey` as combining via concatenating), an `OutputTimeFn` determines the *timestamp* of the output of a grouping transform.

The SDK provides some common choices:

- `OutputTimeFns.outputAtEndOfWindow()`
- `OutputTimeFns.outputAtEarliestInputTimestamp()`
- `OutputTimeFns.outputAtLatestInputTimestamp()`

The default today is `outputAtEarliestInputTimestamp()`, which allows the greatest flexibility in terms of what timestamps you can apply to elements produced downstream but unfortunately at the (necessary) cost of holding up the watermark.

If you do not intend to explicitly output at timestamps within the window, choosing `outputAtEndOfWindow()` allows the watermark to advance as quickly as possible.

***Note***: This feature is marked `Experimental`. That means that its API may change (for example, instead of accepting an arbitrary `OutputTimeFn` implementation, it may be limited to a few fixed constants). The concept is almost certain to remain, as we will always need to decide upon a timestamp for outputs of a grouping transform.

If you still want to cut your sessions up for other reasons, please do comment and I will elaborate on other options for that.

As an aside, I highly recommend the simplified trigger syntax we now provide:

```java
AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()
    .withEarlyFirings(
        AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()
            .plusDelayOf(earlyFiringInterval))
    .withLateFirings(
        AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()
            .plusDelayOf(lateFiringInterval))
```

Comment: Do you mean to say that the `AfterEach.repeatedly(...)` trigger in the question and the one that you mentioned at the end of your post are equivalent?

Comment: I do wish to cut the sessions as the options above with the `outputTimeFns` (although useful) don't help me figure out a degenerate case where some sessions that can potentially last multiple days (generally a client side bug) may hold the watermark back for days.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it out. Is there a way to do the limiting based on maximum window/session duration?

Comment: To your first comment: The trigger expression in my answer is equivalent to the first one from your question. You can still append the same .originally(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(...) to achieve your later trigger.

Comment: I suspect I need to know more about your end goal to give the best answer. I am inclined to suggest that keeping the session intact and filtering degenerate data downstream is the best solution.

If the trigger terminates a session early, then all the data that would have kept the session open will just start a new session. My sense is that if this is a degenerate session caused by a client bug you wouldn't want to split it into a multitude of normal-looking session. This will also give unpredictable results in the presence of late data.

Comment: Another approach I want to caution about would be a variation on the Sessions WindowFn that stops merging after a session reaches its maximum length. This is also not robust to late data.